# How to unit test code wrapped in `runOnUiThread`?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-runonuithread

I have a function that calls `runOnUiThread` as below

```
fun myFunction(myObject: MyClass, view: MyView) {
    // Do something
    view.getActivity().runOnUiThread {
        myObject.myObjectFunction()
    }
}
```

I want to UnitTest `myFunction` to ensure the `myObject` has call `myObjectFunction`. But given that it is wrap in `runOnUiThread`, I can't get to it.

How could I unit test to ensure codes within `runOnUiThread` is called?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Manage to find a way to perform the test using `ArgumentCaptor`. Capture the `Runnable` in the `runOnUiThread()` function, and then trigger the run through `runOnUiArgCaptor.value.run()`

```
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.argumentCaptor
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.verify
import com.nhaarman.mockito_kotlin.whenever
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.mockito.Mock

@Mock lateinit var activity: Activity
@Mock lateinit var view: MyView
@Mock lateinit var myObject: MyObject

@Before
fun setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)
}

@Test
fun my_test_function() {
    whenever(view.getActivity()).thenReturn(activity)

    val runOnUiArgCaptor = argumentCaptor<Runnable>()
    val myTestObject = TestObject()

    myTestObject.myFunction(myObject, view)
    verify(activity).runOnUiThread(runOnUiArgCaptor.capture())
    runOnUiArgCaptor.value.run()

    verify(myObject).myObjectFunction()

}
```